# Integration by part in dimension 2

Tags: real-analysis, stokes-theorem

I have an operator $\mathcal{L}$ defined for functions $u(x,y)$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$
$$\mathcal{L}:=x\partial_{xx}+\sqrt{xy}\partial_{xy}+\frac12y\partial_{yy}+2\rho\partial_x+\rho\partial_y.$$
I want to perform an integration by part for the integral
$$
I:=\int\int_{x,y>0}\mathcal{L}u\cdot f dxdy
$$
where $f$ is also a function on $\mathbb{R}^2$.I want to find an adjoint operator $\mathcal{L}^*$ such that
$$
I=\int\int_{x,y>0}u\cdot\mathcal{L}^*f dxdy.
$$
I guess it is a quite standard operation. I know it is related somehow to Stoke's theorem, but cannot figure out how to do this. Can anyone please give some hint on how to do this, or give me some reference? Thank you!

Comment: Is $\mathcal{L}u = x\partial_{xx}u + \sqrt{xy}\partial_{xy}u+\frac{1}{2}y\partial_{yy}u+2\rho\partial_x\color{red}{u\cdot u}+\rho\partial_y\color{red}{u\cdot u}$?  If so, it appears $\mathcal{L}$ currently depends on $u$.

Comment: Anyway, if we ignore those terms there seems to be a typo in for now this isn't too hard.  Write $I = \iint (x\partial_{xx}uf+\sqrt{xy}\partial_{xy}uf+\frac{1}{2}y\partial_{yy}uf) = \iint x\partial_{xx}uf+\iint \sqrt{xy}\partial_{xy}uf+\iint\frac{1}{2}y\partial_{yy}uf$.  Then, we just need to find the above easier adjoints (for $\mathcal{L}_1 = x\partial_{xx}$, $\mathcal{L}_2 = \sqrt{xy}\partial_{xy}$, and $\mathcal{L}_3 = \frac{1}{2}y\partial_{yy}$), after which we can recombine them to get what we want.  These ones can all be done via integration by parts.

Comment: Also, what is known about $u$? Integration by parts will pick up extra "ugly" factors unless it's known how $u$ decays/acts on the boundary of integration.